# What is the correct way to handle default kernelopts in Fedora 31?

Tags: fedora, grub2, grub2-mkconfig

I'm running Fedora 31 and when I installed it (F29) I added the option `mem_sleep_default=deep` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`. Now I wanted to remove that option but found the file like this:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

I remember there have been many more options like `rd.lvm.lv` or `rd.luks.uuid` which luckily still are in `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` but I can't find them anywhere else.

I think things might have changed since the upgrade to F30 or F31. Also I noticed that `GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true` might mean that things are done different now. I read that I shouldn't use `grub2-mkconfig` any more but grubby to change kernelopts. But I fear to loose all my kernelopts which I think are important.

So what is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the recommended approach is to use `grubby`:

```
grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

will add the given argument to the kernel command line, and

```
grubby --update-kernel=ALL --remove-args=mem_sleep_default
```

will remove it.

`grubby` minimises the changes made, and when updating kernel parameters, the above will preserve the other parameters (based on those used to boot the currently-running kernel).

`/etc/default/grub` isn’t necessarily the reference file for boot parameters; AFAICT on EFI systems you should look at `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv` (or rather, `/boot/grub2/grubenv`).

See [the GRUB 2 wiki page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2) on the Fedora wiki for some complementary information.